# React.Js 0.14 - Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs

> **I have 2 sub classes and 1 super class (3 components):**
>
> 1. Navigation (super)
> 2. TopNavZone
> 3. MobileNavZone

---

```
export default class Navigation extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      navItems: [],
      navMenu: []
   };
 }

 fetchNavItems(clientId) {
   NavMenuAPI.getAll(clientId)
     .then((response) => {
       const data = response.data;
       this.setState({ navItems: data });
       this.showNavMenu();
     });
   }
 }
```

---

Each sub class calls the fetch method in componentDidMount, and then the fetch call, after getting the data, calls the respective sub class's showMenu method:

---

```
export default class TopNavZone extends Navigation {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const clientId = this.props.clientId;
    // in super class
    this.fetchNavItems(clientId);
 }

 showNavMenu() {
   const navItems = this.state.navItems;
   const results = [];
   navItems.map((item, index) => {
    results.push(

     // whatever html markup belongs here for TopNavZone

   );
 });
   this.setState({ navMenu: results });
}

 render() {
   if (!this.state.navMenu) return <div>Loading</div>;
   return (
    <div>{ this.state.navMenu }</div>
   )
}
```

---

I know what the error message is telling me. I know React no longer allows objects to be rendered as a child. I tried ...

```
React.addons.createFragment(results)
```

in the showNavMenu and received the error that cannot create fragment of undefined.

I like as much of my html away from the render section and refactored into the respective functions that deal with it, so I really do not want to load up my render section with the showNavMenu markup. I'd just assume call it in one line from the render section.

***What must I do to make this work and keep a tidy render section?***

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and have kept the render section tidy.

***The key to my solution lies in performing the mapping inside the render and NOT calling a function to perform that same said mapping***.

So .......

1. Remove the this.showNavMenu() from the super class' fetchNavItems, and the navMenu array from state.
2. Render now looks like this:

   ```
   render() {
     if (!this.state.navItems) return <div>Loading ...</div>;
     return (
       <section>
         <nav>
           <ul>
              { this.state.navItems.map(this.showNavMenu.bind(this)) }
          </ul>
        </nav>
     </section>
    );
   }
   ```
3. showNavMenu has changed to:

   ```
   showNavMenu(item) {
     const results = [];
     let subMenu = [];
     let childrenLength = 0;
     if (item.children !== undefined) {
       const children = item.children;
       childrenLength = children.length;
       subMenu = this.fetchSubMenu(children);
     }
     results.push(
       <li key={ item.index }>
           { item.title }
         </Link>
         { subMenu }
       </li>
     );
     return results;
   }
   ```
4. fetchSubMenu:

   ```
    fetchSubMenu(children) {
     const results = [];
     children.map((child, idx) => {
       results.push(
         <div key={ idx }>
             <Link to={ child.linkTo }>
               { child.title }
             </Link>
         </div>
       );
     });
     return results;
   }
   ```